# Since Xcode 13.3, I'm seeing an error when compiling in Terminal with -flto

Tags: xcode, terminal, compiler-errors, clang, handbrake

On macOS 12.3 I am working on a patch to build HandBrake with `-flto`. It then can be build in Terminal with `./configure --lto`. This worked nicely with Xcode 13.2 and 13.2.1 installed. But since I have updated to Xcode 13.3 (compiler updated to Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)) it fails with the following error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-macos10.13 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -L/Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/xroot -L/Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/libhb -L/Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/contrib/lib -F/Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/xroot -filelist /Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/xroot/HandBrakeCLI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HandBrakeCLI.LinkFileList -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/xroot/HandBrakeCLI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HandBrakeCLI_lto.o -filelist /Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/macosx/osl.filelist.txt -lc++ -w -framework Foundation -liconv -lbz2 -lz -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework VideoToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -lavfilter -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreServices -framework IOKit -lopus -lhandbrake -lass -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lbluray -ldav1d -ldvdnav -ldvdread -lspeex -lturbojpeg -lfreetype -lfribidi -lmp3lame -llzma -lpostproc -logg -lswscale -ltheora -lvorbis -lswresample -lvorbisenc -lvpx -lx264 -lxml2 -ljansson -lharfbuzz -lzimg -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/xroot/HandBrakeCLI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HandBrakeCLI_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/xroot/HandBrakeCLI
ld: linking module flags 'override-stack-alignment': IDs have conflicting values in '/Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/contrib/lib/libx264.a(base.o)' and 'ld-temp.o' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/Nomis101/Documents/GitHub/HandBrakeKopie/build/xroot/HandBrakeCLI normal (in target 'HandBrakeCLI' from project 'HandBrake')
(1 failure)
make: *** [macosx.build] Error 65
```

I've tried already to remove and compile the necessary toolchain (nasm, cmake...) with the same version of Xcode. I've reinstalled the CommandLineTools, I removed them completely. I've added flags -fno-stack-check and similar. Nothing helped. I have no idea what the reason of this is, I'm really lost right now. I also could not find anything in the Release Notes of Xcode 13.3.